# Export private key without keypass from Java Key Store without storepass

Tags: java, keystore, jks

I have a **JKS keystore without a storepass**, which contains a **private key without a keypass**.

- I can't use this store and this key to *interactively* sign using e.g. `jarsigner` (which does not allow for empty keypass),
- and all *automation* fails either by demanding a storepass or a keypass or both.

**But the private key *is* in the keystore.**

All my attempts at extracting the key using `keytool` have failed, and all attempts to password protect the key or the keystore have failed as well, all owing to the passlessness. The same goes for GUI and other tools that manipulate keystores. I'm *guessing* this is because a keypassless key in a storepassless store isn't a supported scenario anymore, or perhaps never was.

But I'm guessing there's code in the `java.security.KeyStore` namespace or elsewhere that lets me export the private key using Java code. Does anyone know for sure, and if so, could point me in the right direction, since I have zero experience with this?

Comment: Are you sure the password is not the default password 'changeit' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some Java code using `KeyStore` to export a private key [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150195/3474)

It's not clear what you mean when you say that you have "no" password. A JKS key store requires a key store password and a password for each secret and private key entry. However, this password can be the empty string. If that's what you mean, use `new char[0]` as the password, like this:

```
KeyStore keys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
 /* You don't actually need the password to open the store. */
try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("identity.jks")) {
  keys.load(is, null);
}
char[] password = new char[0];
/* Continue with example from linked answer. */
...
```

The command line tools won't work without specifying arguments for these, but have you tried specifying an empty string? I.e., `-storepass ""`? You can also change passwords on the store itself or an individual key entry so that the password is no longer empty and the tools will not complain.