# Import existing private key into BKS Keystore

Tags: java, android, security, rsa, keytool

I have a key pair generated by openssl in the following way

> openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

The I convert it to DER format as follow

> openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem \
>   -out private_key.der -nocrypt

And now I want to import it in android but I don't want import it as it I want to protect it within a keystore.

So my question is how can I import a existing key into BKS keystore using keytool?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Private Key` is always accompanied by a `Certificate Chain` (that includes the corresponding Certificate) in a KeyStore. You cannot just add it to the KeyStore just by itself.

Once you have generated the `Private Key`, you can generate a self-signed Certificate, you can then use this certificate to add your private key along with the certificate to the KeyStore.

**Generating self-signed Certificate**

> openssl req -new -x509 -key [PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] -out [SELF_SIGNED_CERTIFICATE_FILE]
>   -days 3650 -subj /[YOUR_SUBJECT_DN]

**Creating a PKCS#12 file containing the PrivateKey and the Certificate**

> openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey [PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] -in
>   [CERTIFICATE_FILE] -out [PKCS12_FILE.p12] -name mykey

**Finally, converting the PKCS12 KeyStore to your desired `BKS` store type**

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [ABOVE_P12_FILE] -srcstorepass [ABOVE_P12_PASSWORD]
>   -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore [NEW_P12_FILE.p12] -deststorepass [NEW_P12_PASSWORD] -deststoretype bks -providerclass
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath
>   [ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO__bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar]

If you need the Java default store type `JKS`, you can remove the `-providerclass` and `-providerpath` arguments from the last command.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but now with PKCS#12 file, how can I read the private key in java?

Comment: You can refer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150167/how-do-i-list-export-private-keys-from-a-keystore and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm

Comment: The second command might not work (I was running it in git bash), so you should do ```winpty bash``` before. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156938/openssl-hangs-during-pkcs12-export-with-loading-screen-into-random-state) for more info